# Angular shared component that extends class is complaining about unknown properties

Tags: angular, inheritance

I hope someone can help; I will try to explain this as best as I can.

I have a table component which many components extend. The base table component looks like this:

```
export class DataTableBaseComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    @Input() subject: BehaviorSubject<any[]>;
    @Input() loadingSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
    @Input() itemsPerPage: number;
    @Input() multiSelect = true;

    @Output() onItemRemoved: EventEmitter<any>;
    @Output() onItemUpdated: EventEmitter<any>;
    @Output() onItemSelected: EventEmitter<any[]>;
    @Output() onItemMoved: EventEmitter<any[]>;
    @Output() onItemAdded: EventEmitter<any[]>;
    @Output() onCount: EventEmitter<number>;

    public items: any[];
    public loading: boolean;

    private firstInit: boolean = true;
    private subjectSubscription: Subscription;
    private loadingSubscription: Subscription;
    private copiedItems: any[];
    private filteredItemsListObs: Observable<any[]>;
    private filteredItemsListSubject: BehaviorSubject<any[]>;
    private filteredItemsListSubscription: Subscription;

    filters: {
        searchTerm: string;
        itemsPerPage: number;
    };

    public keys: string[];
    public filteredItems: any[];
    public sortedBy: {
        key: string;
        direction: 'asc' | 'desc';
    };

    constructor(public router: Router) {
        this.filters = { ...baseFilters };
        this.loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject(true);
        this.filteredItemsListSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]);
        this.filteredItemsListObs = this.filteredItemsListSubject.asObservable();
        this.onItemRemoved = new EventEmitter();
        this.onItemUpdated = new EventEmitter();
        this.onItemSelected = new EventEmitter();
        this.onItemMoved = new EventEmitter();
        this.onItemAdded = new EventEmitter();
        this.onCount = new EventEmitter();
    }

    /*** --- omitted for brevity --- ***/
}
```

**Please note:** The base table class has no decorator, so it's not imported anywhere.

I have hundreds (literally) of components that extend the base class like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-locations-table',
    templateUrl: './locations-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./locations-table.component.scss'],
})
export class LocationsTableComponent extends DataTableBaseComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        public router: Router,

        private dialog: MatDialog,
        private locationService: LocationService,
        private dialogService: DialogService,
    ) {
        super(router);
    }

    onInitCallback() {
        this.sortBy('id');
    }

    handleDelete() {
        this.delete(this.selectedItems.map((item) => item.id));
    }

    delete(ids: number[]) {
        this.deleteMultiple(ids);
    }

    edit(model: Location) {
        const modalRef = this.dialogService.open(SaveLocationComponent, model);

        modalRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: Location) => {
            if (result) {
                this.updateItem(result);
            }
        });
    }

    private deleteMultiple(ids: number[]): void {
        const modalRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
            data: { message: 'Deleting a location will remove any data related to it. Do you wish to continue?' },
        });

        modalRef.afterClosed().subscribe((accepted) => {
            if (accepted) {
                combineLatest(ids.map((id) => this.locationService.delete(id))).subscribe(() => {
                    ids.forEach((id) => this.removeItem(id));
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Which I can use like this:

```
<app-locations-table [subject]="subject" [loadingSubject]="loadingSubject"></app-locations-table>
```

Which I have done in a new **LocationsComponent**:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './Locations.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./Locations.component.scss'],
})
export class LocationsComponent implements OnInit {
    public theatreId: number;
    public venueId: number;

    public subject: BehaviorSubject<Location[]>;
    public loadingSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,

        private LocationService: LocationService,
        private dialogService: DialogService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            this.theatreId = params.theatreId;
            this.venueId = params.venueId;
            this.subject = this.LocationService.items;
            this.loadingSubject = this.LocationService.loading;
            this.LocationService.list(this.theatreId).subscribe();
        });
    }

    public create($event?: MouseEvent) {
        $event && $event.stopPropagation();

        const model: Location = {
            id: 0,
            theatreId: this.theatreId,
            name: '',
        };

        this.dialogService.open(SaveLocationComponent, model);
    }
}
```

And the module looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SharedModule } from '@shared';
import { LocationsRoutingModule } from './locations-routing.module';
import { LocationsComponent } from './locations.component';
import { LocationsTableComponent } from './locations-table/locations-table.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [LocationsComponent, LocationsTableComponent],
    imports: [CommonModule, LocationsRoutingModule, SharedModule],
})
export class LocationsModule {}
```

The strange thing is this works fine when testing locally, no compilation errors and when I deploy using dev, again no issues.
But if I run `ng build --prod` I get this error:

```
src/app/locations/Locations.component.html:28:34 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'subject' since it isn't a known property of 'app-locations-table'.
1. If 'app-locations-table' is an Angular component and it has 'subject' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-locations-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

28             <app-locations-table [subject]="subject" [loadingSubject]="loadingSubject"></app-locations-table>
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/locations/locations.component.ts:11:18
    11     templateUrl: './Locations.component.html',
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component LocationsComponent.
src/app/locations/Locations.component.html:28:54 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'loadingSubject' since it isn't a known property of 'app-locations-table'.
1. If 'app-locations-table' is an Angular component and it has 'loadingSubject' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-locations-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

But as you can see, **app-locations-table** is defined in the module.
If I change the html to this:

```
<app-locations-table></app-locations-table>
```

The error goes away, but the table obviously doesn't work.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

---

Looks like it has something to do with this:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38660

Comment: Have you checked the documentation as mentioned in the comment?

Comment: Yeah, trying to make sense of it

Comment: If you want detailed explanation check this:https://hackmd.io/@alx/S1XKqMZeS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the link above suggests, I was able to fix this with:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appDataTable]' })
export class DataTableBaseComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
}
```